# Print out num rows only selecting user2_id's

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to print out only the number of rows containing user2_ids within my streamdata_feedback table and it seems to be printing out both the user2_id and the user1_id. How can I rectify this issue with the below code?

```
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$user2_id=$data['id'];

$likesqltwo = "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata_feedback
    WHERE feedback_rating = 1
        AND feedback_userid = " . $user2_id .
        "AND feedback_streamid = " . $streamid;

$likequerytwo = mysql_query($likesqltwo);
$num3 = mysql_num_rows($likequerytwo);
if ($num3 > 0)
{
    echo "And <a title = 'See who likes " .
        $poster_name['fullusersname'] .
        "s status' href='include/likes.php?streamitem_id=" .
        $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' />" . 
        $num3 . " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a client for your MySQL database? I'd recommend picking up [SqlYog Community Edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/). You can then execute your query against it and see how many rows are returned outside of PHP code. Once you have a satisfactory query, then incorporate it into your PHP project.

Next tip: You can include variables from PHP directly in strings with double quotes. PHP will parse the variable, and you needn't concatenate. For example:

```
$likesqltwo =
    "SELECT *
    FROM streamdata_feedback
    WHERE feedback_rating = 1
    AND feedback_userid = $user2_id
    AND feedback_streamid = $streamid;";
```

However this code still has a potential flaw, and that's [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/161052). So ensure that the variables you include are *not* coming from users, or [follow the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/161052) to learn more about preventing such things. That's not what you asked for help on, but I thought it was worth a mention.

To find out how many times the `feedback_userid` equals `$user2_id` for a particular `feedback_streamid` and for only `feedback_rating` values of 1, you could try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM streamdata_feedback
WHERE feedback_rating = 1
AND feedback_userid = 123
AND feedback_streamid = 456;
```

Substitute your primary key for `id`, and the correct user id and stream id for 123 and 456 respectively. If you get an unexpected number of results, I recommend removing `COUNT(id)` and selecting the columns of interest so you can inspect and see why you're getting more rows than you thought.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But the last bit doesn't really help me. I could put the ids in manually, but I need the php to do that. All I need is the number of likes on a given post echoed out not including the like I've made that is obviously the currently logged in $_SESSION['id'] in the database

In some respect my code needs to say..If user2_id has liked this post echo '1 other person liked this' else echo nothing. Tho I don't know how to write it. 

Currently it shows YOU and 1 other likes this post. When only I've liked it. Its clearly selecting my like from the database.

Comment: I tell a lie. Its working on the top post. Just not the rest below it.This is weird.